# Regarding conversion to Integral form.

Tags: integration, prime-numbers

We know that $$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} \left(n\right) = N! = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^N e^{-x} dx$$
On similar basis, we can write that $$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} p(n+m) = p^N\times \frac{(N+m)!}{m!}=p^N \times\frac{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y^{(N+m)}e^{-y}dy}{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} z^m e^{-z}dz}$$
However, when I try to write for $$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} \sin\left(n\right)$$I am stuck. I am getting no idea how to represent $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin\left(n\right)$ in a similar form as I did for others. 
 What I tried is \begin{equation}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin\left(n\right) = \sin(1)\sin(2)\sin(3)\cdots\sin(N)=a!=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} s^a e^{-s}ds\end{equation} but I don't find it much impresssive.
Another approach by me was :$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n)=\sin(n_1)\sin(n_2)\cdots\sin(n_N)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(n_1t_1)\cos(n_2t_2)\cdots\cos(n_Nt_N) dt_1dt_2\cdots dt_N$$where $n_1, n_2,\ldots,n_N$ represent consecutive values.
 But, won't it be too daunting task to follow above approach when $N$ becomes too large?
I want to know if there is some other method for the same (I tried Pochhammer symbol, but I want to know if there is a simpler way than that).
[EDIT: My this question is inspired by a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3997498/875207) asked by me. Since I not received so satisfactory answer there, I decided to proceed on my own; but then I got stuck at this point. So, please help !
Thanks.]

Comment: What gives you confidence that what you have in mind is even possible? And what's your metric by which any integral form would be "impressive" enough? It's hard to tackle a problem without some definition of what success would look like. Also note that a product of sins of integers is probably never going to be equal to the factorial of an integer.

Comment: ya, I know it...but there's nothing wrong in trying. Please refer to my previous question for original motive behind this question.